# Excel- Sum groups of similar cell contents using wildcards

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to sum the amounts in column B based on the types of symbols in column A. Any symbol with "EW" at the start needs to be grouped and by date month - see column D. The second symbol comes in two formats but also needs to be grouped, so "OES" and "OMSX" needs to be grouped together and with their date month. I know I need wildcards here but I cannot get this to work.

**EDIT, correct EW, accidentally had "EWS" before, apologies to anyone who responded**

[image]

Comment: Is it EW or EWS? OE or OES? There appears to be some discrepency.

Comment: ^^ Yes. I can't tie your `Type` column to your `Symbols` column really.

Comment: What have you tried?  I can think of `SUMIFS`, Pivot table with a helper column.

Comment: You need something like `=SUMIFS(B2:B100,A2:A100,"*EW*",A2:A100,"*DEC*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thius should work if you can get your data corrected.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, REPLACE(D2, FIND(" ", D2), LEN(D2), "*"), A:A, REPLACE(D2, 1, FIND(" ", D2), "*")&"*")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works for the EW ones but not the others. I was thinkning that the symbols being within the actual formula rather than referencing the cells in column D would be better. Because, this one cannot be referenced: "OES & OMSX Jan". They need to be lumped together but don't share the same 3-4 letters.

Comment: If you insist on a formula approach, I see no reason why you couldn't modify the above for duel symbols.

Comment: I have tried to do this but I cannot. Thanks for the help, this solution is much better than what I had originally.